# compiling nested functions with clang versus gcc

Tags: gcc, clang, llvm

I have a c file that I can compile with no problem using `GCC` like below:

`gcc foo.c`

however using the same file I am receiving error of having defined functions inside main using `clang`:

`clang foo.c`

```
foo:230:1: error: function definition is not allowed here
{
^
foo.c:241:1: error: function definition is not allowed here
{
^
foo.c:253:1: error: function definition is not allowed here
```

these instances of errors are the definitions of a new function inside the main section of the code. I want to know why GCC doesn't get bothered with this yet clang does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions defined within functions are an extension to the C language, implemented by gcc. This is enabled by default. If you make gcc a Standard C compiler, as with `-ansi -pedantic` or `-std=C99` or similar, it will also complain about nested function definitions:

```
x.c: In function ‘main’:
x.c:8:5: warning: ISO C forbids nested functions [-Wpedantic]
     int nested(void)
     ^
```

Comment: thanks @Jens. Do you know whether or not this had been implemented in clang as well?

Comment: @Amir As of clang 4.0.0, clang doesn't support nested functions. Why would you want them? If you are in control of the source code, you can rewrite the source and move the nested functions to file scope.

Comment: @Jens Nested functions are sometimes useful. For instance, we use them in GNU MPFR for (optional) logging support: such functions are defined via a macro expansion used inside a function. Getting rid of nested functions would mean splitting macros and making sure that there are no conflicts between identifiers, and this would make the code less readable and less maintainable.

Comment: @Jens: nested functions are akin to C++ lambdas -- they can access the enclosing function variables. Unlike C++ lambdas, though, they are convertible to a simple function pointer even when they do access the enclosing scope. The former can be done by relocating the function to the global scope and passing an extra context argument down the call chain (though it is verbose), the later cannot be done without compiler support for nested function.

Comment: @Jens, "why would you want functions in file scope?  If you are in control of the source code, you can rewrite the entire program in `main` and use `goto`s to jump around as necessary.  Or you can just rewrite the source in assembly."  Yeesh...  Are we _seriously_ on a programming site asking "why would you do X in language Y when I can think of method Z to achieve a similar result in a more verbose fashion?"

Comment: @Jens: just bumped into this... indeed local functions within macro expansion (or `({...})` syntax) can make the code in certain cases extremely more readable and maintainable. That this is not allowed in the standard is a defect in the standard.
Long ago "standard" meant formalization and unification of what the actual users found was working well... now seems it's just what some guys decide because... well... just because.